# Iterating with rails and using bootstrap to get cards to display in columns of 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to get iterate through rails to create cards that grid in 3 then new line etc using each. Currently the cards only stack vertically. I would like them to be in columns of 3 and then resize to stack when the screen is made small.

Currently my code looks like this:
https://i.imgur.com/mnbDIl5.png

And when I make my screen smaller it appears to go to a 3x3 like this:
https://i.imgur.com/G2T9leW.png

Could anyone please help/suggest where I am going wrong?

Currently using Bootstrap  v5.2.2

Thanks in advance!

```
<div class="card text-center text-white row row-cols-3 row-cols-md-3" style="background-color:#ffa82e00;">
  <% @drinks.each do |drink| %>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="card photo" class="card-img-top">
          <%= cl_image_tag drink.photo.key, height: 350, width: 350, crop: :fit if drink.photo.attached? %>
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title"><%= link_to drink.name, drink_path(drink) %></h5>
            <p class="card-text">Price: £<%= drink.price %></p>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"><%= link_to "Buy now", new_drink_order_path(drink) %></button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

The cards only stack 1 by 1 no matter the viewport size, and my novice knowledge of bootstrap is hindering me from getting them to display in columns of 3.

Comment: You'll get better response if you show us rendered HTML that we can fiddle with here. Please tag your Bootstrap version.

Comment: Hi @isherwood, thank you for getting back to me - apologise for the lack of info, I have inserted screenshots/edits of what the html is doing and on bootstrap 5.2.2. Thanks again!

Comment: Please _tag_ your Bootstrap version. Also, screenshots are not helpful. Please see [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```html
<div class="row">
<% @drinks.each do |drink| %>
  <div class="col-12 col-lg-4">
      <div class="card text-center text-white" style="background-color:#ffa82e00;">
        <div class="card photo" class="card-img-top">
          <%= cl_image_tag drink.photo.key, height: 350, width: 350, crop: :fit if drink.photo.attached? %>
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title"><%= link_to drink.name, drink_path(drink) %></h5>
            <p class="card-text">Price: £<%= drink.price %></p>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"><%= link_to "Buy now", new_drink_order_path(drink) %></button>
          </div>
        </div>  
      </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
</div>
```

You can wrap cards in the grid like that. This will make a grid of 3 cards wide on lg screens and above then reduces down to 1 column below that.

The loop also changed slightly to more correctly duplicate the card itself, and not extra code.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/layout/grid/

The docs above explain the columns in a bit more detail. Version 5.2 automatically handles wrapping columns after 12 columns are exceeded, so this should be all you need!

Comment: Thank you RShannon - this works great! Going to read up on the documentation now! Much appreciated